# Error with gradle and vaadin build failure in eclipse but works fine with terminal

Tags: java, gradle, vaadin, vaadin7, gradle-eclipse

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/atapare/git/dvh/modules/mdvh/build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':modules:mdvh'.

  > No signature of method: build_16j80bhfkqt2bfhcii98quk3mb$_run_closure1.id() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin]
  >   Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), is(java.lang.Object), find(), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Note: it's working good with terminals unable to build using eclipse...
I have installed gradle 2 and vaadin 7 plugin.

Comment: my build.gradle like :plugins {
    id "fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin" version "0.9.7"
}

vaadin.version=vaadinVersion

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: "com.vaadin", module: "vaadin-client-compiler"
    all*.exclude group: "com.vaadin", module: "vaadin-client-compiled"
}...................Can any body help me

Comment: Possible that eclipse is sourcing its own maybe outdated version of gradle? Also maybe this page will help https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html

Comment: Ther error you got is telling you what to try. Would you mind trying them?

Comment: I have latest version of gradle (i.e  3.7.1.201510041001-RELEASE) in the eclipse. I have also installed groovy plugin ..but make no sense..  also update all the plugin  i have in eclipse including vaadin.any one can help me ..pls let me know any plugin i have missed  in the eclipse  for this to build.

Answer (score 1):

To use the new plugin syntax you will need Gradle 2.1 and forward.

You are also using Pivotals Gradle plugin which has by default an old version of Gradle. That Gradle eclipse plugin is no longer maintained and you should uninstall it.

Instead install the [Build Ship Gradle Integration 1.0](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration) by Eclipse Buildship Project. It has the best gradle support and is directly supported by the Gradle community.